# Laravel: send password reset link

Tags: laravel, smtp

**Problem**. When I try to send password reset link with Laravel (v.5.2), i get this error message:

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""
```

How can I fix this?

**.env**.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=send.one.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=info@myemail.se
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

**mail.php**

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'send.one.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
'from' => ['address' => 'info@myemail.se', 'name' => 'donotreply'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

**Other info.** I have my project on a shared host site called one.com. The project is quite small, and not much is changed from the Laravel installation. I uploaded it by copying it into the domain, and changed a few settings.

Comment: Have you tried composer dump-autoload to clear artisan cache?

Comment: I don't think composer is installed, or that I can use it on my shared host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be many settings, my current suspicion would be the `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null`. Have you tried setting it to `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl`? Since it's port 465, it might be neither `null` or `tls` (the `env()` fallback) .

Comment: Thanks! I changed mail_encryption= tls and now it works.